# How to download full content SVF file?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hello Autodesk Forge Team,
I have issue when download svf file from api

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{{urn}}/manifest
```

[image]

When I'm download, it just have file manifest.json and metadata.json, but folder geometry,material,sence is empty, can I know any reason ?

Can I get full information of content svf file include geometry when I'm download svf format by urn ?

Thank you for your help !
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because geometry, materials etc ... are not embedded in the **SVF** file. You need to parse the *manifest.json* to get the relative path to all the resources.

If you want to download the complete **SVF** you can use the [Forge Convert Utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils). There is a sample script that shows you how to use it to download the **SVF**.

Comment: You are right. finally I'm also created a library in .NET same with that library to resolve my problem, thank you for your help.